# Showing first and last name in statusbar

Tags: mysql, delphi, rad-studio

I am a beginner in Delphi, and I would like to show first and last name in the StatusBar instead of the username.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Login do
  begin
    active := false;
    sql.Clear;
    sql.Text := 'SELECT korisnicko, lozinka from operateri where korisnicko = ' + quotedstr(edtkorisnicko.Text) + ' and lozinka = ' + quotedstr(edtlozinka.Text);
    active := true;

    if Login.RecordCount <> 0 then
    begin
      form1.Hide();
      form2.statusbar1.panels[0].text:= 'Korisnik: ' + edtKorisnicko.Text;
      form2.showmodal();
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Korisničko ime ili lozinka nisu validni!');
    end;
  end;
```

**"Korisnicko or edtKorisnicko" standing for "username".**

Answer (score 0):

Given that [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466255/65863) shows the desired name is stored in the `ime_prezime` field of the database record you are searching for, you can simply retrieve that field in the very same `SELECT` query that is searching for the username/password, there is no need to run a 2nd query to get that field value separately, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Login.Close;
  Login.SQL.Text := 'SELECT ime_prezime from operateri where korisnicko = ' + QuotedStr(edtkorisnicko.Text) + ' and lozinka = ' + QuotedStr(edtlozinka.Text);
  Login.Open;
  Login.First;

  if not Login.Eof then
  begin
    Form1.Hide();
    Form2.StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Korisnik: ' + Login.FieldByName('ime_prezime').AsString;
    Form2.ShowModal();
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Korisničko ime ili lozinka nisu validni!');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

There is answer. :)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Login do
  begin
    active := false;
    sql.Clear;
    sql.Text := 'SELECT korisnicko, lozinka from operateri where korisnicko = ' + quotedstr(edtkorisnicko.Text) + ' and lozinka = ' + quotedstr(edtlozinka.Text);
    active := true;

    if Login.RecordCount <> 0 then
    begin
      active := false;
      sql.Clear;
      sql.Text := 'SELECT ime_prezime FROM operateri WHERE korisnicko = ' + quotedstr(edtkorisnicko.Text);
      active := true;
      form1.Hide();
      form2.statusbar1.panels[0].text := 'Korisnik: ' + Login.FieldByName('ime_prezime').Text;
      form2.showmodal();
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Korisničko ime ili lozinka nisu validni!');
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Why not simply select `ime_prezime` in the 1st query and get rid of the 2nd query completely? And why are you selecting `korisnicko` and `lozinka` when you don't actually use them?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is because with first query OP is validating login information. `korisnicko `=`username` and `lozinka`=`password` in Croatian language. And field `ime_prezime` is storing first and last name which is what OP is trying to show.

Comment: @SilverWarior I'm aware of that. That doesn't change what I said. The 2 queries can be merged into 1. I have posted an answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: At least `quotedstr(edtkorisnicko.Text)` should be done only once (storing the outcome to a variable), not again (repeating the same processing). Selecting `ime_prezime` right away and not using it (because login credentials are wrong) needs less performance anyway (instead of issuing a whole new SELECT afterwards).

Comment: Please use parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).